# Linq to Entities Join -- I don't want anonymous types

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have two tables that are related via a mapping table:

1. `keywords`
2. `titles`

I am trying to return a list of `Map_Keywords_Title` (the mapping table's object) based on the results of a join.

Until I added the last part with `typedQuery` it was just returning objects of anonymous type.  I want it to return items of type `Map_Keywords_Title` so I tried adding the Select at the end (also tried Cast but that failed).  The problem now is that the resulting objects are not managed by entity framework so I can't save changes to them.

Is there no straightforward way to do this in Linq to Entities?  I'm using VS2008 so I don't yet have the new EF.

```
    public IList<Map_Keywords_Title> MatchingTitleKeywordMappings(string containedInText)
    {
        var keywords = QueryKeywords();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(containedInText))
        {
            Expression<Func<Keyword, bool>> exprContainsKeyword = k => containedInText.Contains(k.WordText);
            keywords = keywords.Where(exprContainsKeyword);
        }
        var maps = QueryMap_Keywords_Title();
        var anonQuery = keywords.Join(
            maps,
            key => (int)key.Id,
            map => (int)map.Keyword.Id,
            (key, map) => new
            {
                map.Id,
                map.Keyword,
                map.Title
            });
        var typedQuery = anonQuery.ToList().Select(anon => new Map_Keywords_Title()
            {
                Id = anon.Id,
                Keyword=anon.Keyword,
                Title=anon.Title
            });

        return typedQuery.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: I don't believe you need the second query.  Can you change your "new {..." in your first query to "new Map_Keywords_Title {..."?

Comment: It doesn't like that.  It says "Cannot initialize type Map_Keywords_Title with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'.  
Even then, I think I'd still have the problem of creating a "new" Map_Keywords_Title instead of using one that's managed by EF, no?

Comment: Does this help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896271.aspx ?  Sorry, I don't have an easy way to test the code.

Comment: Hmmm...  Maybe.  I'll have to investigate whether there's a way to do this en masse for all returned items instead of one by one.

Comment: You don't need a join if you have endpoints.  Joins should be a last resort in EF. What are the relationship endpoints in the keyword and title classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I got tired of comments...

```
using( someContext sc = new someContext())
{
    sc.Map_Keywords_Title.Include("Title")
                .Include("Keyword")
                .Where( mkt => containedInText.Contains(mkt.Keyword.WordText));
}
```

Is that anywhere close to what you want?